# dot product ValueError: shapes not aligned

Tags: python, numpy

how to fix this

```
V = np.array([[-0.42866713, -0.56630692, -0.7039467 ],
              [ 0.80596391,  0.11238241, -0.58119908],
              [ 0.40824829, -0.81649658,  0.40824829]])
S = np.array([9.508032  , 0.77286964])
np.dot(S, V) #throws error ValueError: shapes (2,) and (3,3) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 3 (dim 0)
```

While this works:

```
U = np.array([[-0.3863177 , -0.92236578],
              [-0.92236578,  0.3863177 ]])
S = np.array([9.508032  , 0.77286964])
np.dot(S, U)
```

I am trying to do SVD reconstruction:

```
M = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
U,S,V = np.linalg.svd(M)

# then i wanted do like np.product(np.product(U, S), V)
# or they do like np.product(U*S, V)
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html

Comment: What mathematical operation do you want to perform? `np.dot` performs a dot product (or an operation similar to a matrix multiplication) which require the vector/matrix to have a [correct size](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)...

Comment: @JérômeRichard i am trying to do the SVD reconstruction and this is what comes out of it. what do you suggest to make it working, should i fill remaining dimensions of S with zeros or ones, or what do i do? or U actually because U dot V doesn't work either.

Comment: To me, if you have different size, it means that there is a bug in you program before. You can perform some padding with 0, but it means ya you will ignore some dimension which is generally bad (not something intended). So you need to understand why the size mismatch, not just "make it works".

Answer (score 1):

As the `ValueError` suggests, S should have 3 values or V should have only 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by calling:

```
U * S @ V[:2]
```

V[:2] means keep only first 2 rows and all columns from matrix V